# Controlling the Linux C++ build environment from MSVC

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2019

I have found that using MSVC to write C++ code and push to Linux to debug works fairly well for a simple environment where you just take the default gcc, cmake, etc.

But, does anyone know how to control the version of gcc, cmake, etc?   Depending on the situation I may need to target several different compilers.   Has anyone had any luck controling the core toolchain from MSVC?

It would be great if there is a way to just set up different build configurations.

Comment: If when you upgrade you leave the previous g++ compiler installed, you can simply invoke it.  Currently, my compiler is g++ 9.2.1., and it is installed as both g++ and g++-9.  My default compile command is "time make CC='g++ $(m) -O0 ' t3".  To use (for example) v8 compiler, I simply insert the -8: "time make CC='g++-8 $(m) -O0 ' t3".  A make file can do several other approaches to selecting the g++ version, but I suppose this might not be "control from MSVC", which I have never used.

Comment: Yeah, but how can you drive that from MSVC?   That's the tough part.  On the Linux side it's easy enough to have a little .sh to switch versions.  But from MSVC you can only kick of a generic build.  I'm sure there's a way to customize but it's not obvious.